# Calling InitializeComponent in OnAppearing method in Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there any reason or problem I cant call InitializeComponent method in OnAppearing function of a page in xamarin forms project?
I understand that I must call InitializeComponent only once to create the actual page. But what if I check that Content is already created and do it as below. Is it a bad implementation or practice? because it is said that no xaml based application does it and always call it in a constructor of the page.

reason I want to do it as below because xamarin.forms start up time is slow running on Android and if you use Masterdetail page(I think same for tabbed page), you must initialize it at the start up, it causes every navigation page defined in masterdetail page to be initialized and it costs you 2-3 secs depending on your UI could be even higher cost. any thoughts or experiences on this?

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
 {    
   if (Content == null)
    {
     InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this approach. From the xamarin docs.

The constructor of that class calls InitializeComponent, which then calls the LoadFromXaml method that extracts the XAML file (or its compiled binary) from the PCL. LoadFromXaml initializes all the objects defined in the XAML file, connects them all together in parent-child relationships, attaches event handlers defined in code to events set in the XAML file, and sets the resultant tree of objects as the content of the page.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/

If your forms are too slow on Android I would enable Fast Renders instead

In the OnCreate of your main activity add this line of code just before Xamarin.Forms.Init

```
Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
```

https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-fastrenderers-android/

It would not hurt to try to use compiled Xaml also

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
...
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class HomePage : ContentPage
{
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: fast renderers are already enabled but they dont help for the startup. this is about masterdetail and tabbedpage performance. and you dont tell me why it meant to be in the constructor. who said that and for what reason? I have even feeling that using onAppearing any page is loading faster if you are using mvvm.

Comment: Updated answer and added an additional recommendation

Comment: hi Ken, thanks for your afford my question not about any of these. I already use them and know all of it. those dont help start up time also. AOT is the only single solution for startup time which causes app size to be larger. my question is about handled code, not about xamarin renderers. your first paragraph is a fair point logically but my experience tells other way around. you can try yourself the see the difference. try on a complicated UI to call as i said and see it that it is slightly faster.